# Crashing the application while adding one storyboard project to xib project in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to i phone programming.Can any body tell me that what is the meaning of this Expection.Here I create one Xib project inside that i have added another project UICollectionview project its contain the storybroad.while i run project its working fine,here if i click on button means it has to go in Collectionview project,But here its crashing the application  and in console its  displaying some message like this.Can any body tell me what is mistake.
Thanks
Aslam

```
Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x9c9e8f0>.
2013-03-06 17:12:04.141 Taukyy[324:1c103] Hai Deselected Aslam
2013-03-06 17:12:04.141 Taukyy[324:1c103] Hai Deselected Aslam
2013-03-06 17:12:05.415 Taukyy[324:1c103] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/81FB53C6-91C6-4609-A3A4-422CF5BA5AF4/Taukyy.app> (loaded)' with name 'LXCollectionViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x25aa012 0x22d8e7e 0x25a9deb 0x1438ef9 0x12fd7e7 0x12fddc8 0x1737437 0x12fdff8 0x12fe232 0x12fe4da 0x13158e5 0x13159cb 0x1315c76 0x1315d71 0x131689b 0x1316e93 0x1316a88 0xb28c8 0x22ec705 0x12202c0 0x145ca64 0x22ec705 0x12202c0 0x1220258 0x12e1021 0x12e157f 0x12e06e8 0x124fcef 0x124ff02 0x122dd4a 0x121f698 0x345cdf9 0x345cad0 0x251fbf5 0x251f962 0x2550bb6 0x254ff44 0x254fe1b 0x345b7e3 0x345b668 0x121cffc 0x3d4d 0x24a5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 0):

On the storyboard you can link UIViewControllers by actions of buttons, like Pressing the Button detail you can push another UIViewController. That is marked with a line on storyboard.

all is fine until you will delete a ViewController and you have forgot to delete the action for that button. On that case you can see exactly that error :)

I hope it helps!

Comment: How can i link action of button to storyboard.Here i have create button dynamically in tableview

Answer (score 0):

When you push that button, you're obviously calling pushViewController:animated method. What this error is saying is that you're pushing a nil to this method. So given the code below,

```
[myNavigationController pushViewContoller:theViewController:animated:YES];
```

the "theViewController" passed to the method is probably not an [[alloc]init]ed  object. It seems that it gets deallocated before you want to push it to the stack.

Comment: I was just going to post this comment to your question when you deleted it... Yes, those options exist in VisualSVN. But source control systems can be rather difficult to use, an unfortunate consequence of their power and versatility. A GUI like VisualSVN is supposed to make them easier to use, but it can only do so much. If you want to use SVN, you might start with [this free book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html). It'll be some time investment, but I would say it's worth it.

Comment: [continued] Just about any professional programmer uses source control nowadays. Although SVN is waning in popularity. The cool kids use Mercurial or Git. There are VS GUIs for both of those as well. There's also a great free tutorial on using Mercurial (Hg) [here](http://hginit.com/). You'll have to decide which pattern you like better. Mercurial and SVN work different ways.